# Can we use InfoPath forms with Microsoft Dynamic CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, infopath

I want to create UI forms for Microsoft Dynamic CRM, where we can fetch the data from CRM and also push the data into CRM.

- Is this achievable using InfoPath (I am using InfoPath 2013).
- Can we create dynamic CRM data connection in infopath? If yes, How?
- Is this an ideal way to use infopath forms with dynamic CRM? If no, what is the best      approach?

Please give me the steps if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5bfff309-7cab-4046-af32-969ff53250b8/how-integrate-infopath-in-crm-2011

http://www.3dcios.com/enright/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=5

Here are some links for you to look at. The second link explains how you can fire an infopath form from a button in ribbon.

To accept data from InfoPath, you should try to integrate it with sharepoint and